# vector space complete in coarse norm but incomplete in finer norm

Tags: normed-spaces, complete-spaces

I would like to see an example of the following situation.

It is well known that $C([0, 1])$ is complete under the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm, but incomplete under the $\|\cdot \|_1$ norm.

Since clearly in this case,
$$
\|\cdot\|_1\leq \|\cdot\|_\infty,
$$
I would call $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ the finer norm since it induces a finer metric topology, and $\|\cdot\|_1$ the coarser norm.

I don't think completeness has relationship with the norm being finer or coarser, so I think there exists an example of a vector space $V$ with two inequivalent norms, say
$$
\|\cdot\|\leq C\|\cdot\|', \quad\text{for some }C>0,
$$
and $V$ is complete in the coarser $\|\cdot\|$, but incomplete in the finer $\|\cdot\|'$.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $(V,\|.\|)$ be a Banach space and $T: V \to V$ be a linear map whose graph is not closed. [I will  let you find an explicit example].

Let $\|x\|'=\|x\|+\|Tx\|$. Then $\|x\|\le \|x\|'$.
There is a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to some $x$ such that $(Tx_n)$ converges to some $y \neq Tx$. This sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $(V,\|.\|')$ but it is not convergent.

Comment: Further hint: There is such a  $T$ with rank $1$ whenever $(V,\|.\|)$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Thank you. This is clear and systematic.

Comment: To flesh out some details after your hints, we can let $V=\ell^1$, $T: \ell^1\to \ell^1; e_n \mapsto ne_1$ where the $(e_n)$ are the standard basis. Then let $x_n = \frac{1}{n} e_n$, we have $x_n\to 0$ but $Tx_n=e_1\neq T0$. Now if $x_n$ were to converge in $\|\cdot\|'$, it must converge in $\|\cdot\|$, so the limit can only be $0$. But $\|x_n-0\|'=\|x_n\| + \|Tx_n\|\to 1$ not 0.